# Add Class To All Fields Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

How do you add a class to all fields at one time using Django Forms?

I know you can define it per field using

```
field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control-sm'}))
```

But thats a lot of boiler plate to add to every field on a model form.

And theres even by looping through the fields in the constructor, but that seems more of a hack than would be neccessarry.

Is there a more generic/ built-in way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

A generic solution from python would be to do it when creating your forms, and perhaps subclass a form that does this so it's done by default;

```
    class MyCustomCSSForm(forms.Form):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for field_name in self.fields:
                self.fields[field_name].widget.attrs.update(
                    {"class": "form-control-sm"}
                )
```